# GoogleMock - return values not match and the test pass

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I'm starting to use Google Mock and I have problem with checking return value.

I have class Turtle and MockTurtle:

```
class Turtle {
public:
  virtual ~Turtle() {}
  virtual int GetX()
  {
    return 10;
  }
};

class MockTurtle : public Turtle {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD0(GetX, int());
};
```

Now I to perform test like this:

```
TEST(PainterTest, CanDrawSomething) 
{
  MockTurtle turtle;
  EXPECT_CALL(turtle, GetX()).Times(1).WillOnce(::testing::Return(1));
  turtle.GetX();
}
```

The test passed, however return value of GetX method (10) do not equal expected (1). What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Mocked methods aren't intended to do any particular thing or return any particular value. If you're just trying to verify that `Turtle::GetX()` returns 1, why are you creating a mock for it?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand how to use ".WillOnce(::testing::Return(X))" correctly. On this site -> https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/ForDummies there is an example of setting expectation (Setting Expectations -> General Syntax), however I do not know how to set them correctly.

Comment: You use mocked objects as accessories as necessary to test unmocked objects. The object being tested shouldn't be a mock. If the object you're testing doesn't interact with other objects, there's no need for a mock. Just test a regular `Turtle`.

Comment: Ok, get it :) Thank you for answer!